# Python nested directories import error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, nested

I have a project where the files and directories are structured as below:

```
Project/
    ├─ __init__.py
    ├─ main.py
    ├─ Utils/
         └─ general_utils.py
         └─ __init__.py
    └─ Baselines/
         └─ __init__.py
         └─ random/
               └─ __init__.py
               └─ random.py
```

In order to run the code, I call `python main.py` and inside `main.py` the script `python Baselines/random/random.py` is called using `os.system`. My problem is I can't find a simple way to import functions from `general_utils.py` inside `random.py`.

I tried

`from Utils.general_utils import *`

and

`from ..Utils.general_utils import *`

Similar questions have been asked before but, everything I try ends up with a "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". Any ideas on how to do this import?

Comment: Why are you calling it from `os.system`? Define functions in the modules and import them in the `main.py` to run them.

Comment: @flakes It's a big project with multiple baselines that have to run in parallel on multiple CPU/GPU's depending on the system specs. The most straight-forward way to do that is to run the files from main.py separately in parallel.

Comment: `from Utils.general_utils import *` should have worked, assuming `.../Project` was in your module import path.

Comment: @A.A. you can still do that, but an easier way which would keep your python path more sane would be using the `multiprocessing` module. Otherwise, look to properly package your project using a pyproject.toml and expose the other entry points as `[project.scripts]`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

Comment: I am using `multiprocessing` but for calling the files instead of defining them as modules. Anyways, I am still looking for a good solution for this specific issue.